# Bootstrap Grid Columnd Fit content

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.4.1.

I've been loking for a responsive list group that will be same height with other components. In the image I want both columns on second row to be same height of image and to hide other list items behind an scrolling group.

Here is the html file : https://jsbin.com/jaqacoq/edit?html,output

```
    <div class="col-md-8 my-col p-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img3.jpg" alt="Image not Found">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 p-2 my-col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row my-row">
                <div class="col my-container">
                    Col 1
                </div>
                <div class="col my-col">
                    Col 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="overflow-auto">
                        <div class="">Item 1</div>
                        <div class="">Item 1</div>
                        <div class="">...</div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Expected result, but without using fixed size : [image: Expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a bit of jQuery to calculate the height of your image so you can set the height of your list group based on that.

With jQuery you can calculate height with `.height()`
Here's an example on how to use it:
`$('#div2').css('height', $('#div1').height()+'px');`

And here's an example with your code that is working:
https://www.codeply.com/p/Pv1dwtjQ9E

Comment: Thanks a lot. It still had an issue when resizing the page but fixed with calling function on resizing :
    `var fitComponentsSize = function () {
        $('#div2').css('height', $('#div1').height() + 'px');
    }

    fitComponentsSize();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        fitComponentsSize();
    });`

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Y-overflow don't work without either `height` or `max-height` option, so you should specify height of your `.comments-block` in any units besides percents.

Another approach I can think of: `position: fixed` all your interface elements and resize/scroll only the central element.